# Setup ASP.NET Web API to do work on a specific thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I'm trying to write an add-in for another piece of software through its .NET API which would allow me to remotely control and read information from it over an HTTP REST interface. So far I've successfully been able to setup a `HttpSelfHostServer` within my add-in and it is responding to HTTP requests that return static data.

The problem I have though is the .NET API for this software only allows accessing data from specific threads created by the API itself. Usually this is an instance of a custom `Command` class which is triggered by a user requesting to run the command. However, there is also an `Application.Idling` event which is fire by the application whenever it is sitting idle and available to do something. There is a way to request that the application idle, but the ultimately the actual `Idling` event will be on a different thread then my Web API request.

Here's a sequence diagram of what I'm trying to do.

[image: Sequence Diagram]

This looks like multi-threading programming 101, but I seem to write just enough multi-threaded code to forget everything I learned the last time I used it.

My first thought was to create a custom delegate for a task as shown below.

`public delegate object Task(Application app);`

However once the delegate instance is run in the idle event I'm not sure how to get the result back to the controller method.

Alternatively I could also make a Task class with a variables to store the function I want to perform and to store the result.

```
public class Task
{
    public Func<UIApplication, object> Task { get; set; }
    public object Result { get; set; }
}
```

What's the best way to go about synchronizing all this? I'd done a little multi-threaded programming but it's never clear me to me when I should be using lock, monitor, mutex, AutoResetEvent etc... Also I've yet to use any of the new async/await functionality. I've been reading some tutorials, but haven't yet figured out how to apply it to my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice question. If you are absolutely certain this is the only way to proceed, then one solution would be to put a [`TaskCompletionSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174(v=vs.110).aspx) in your queue that could be completed by the add-in. Your API controller could then wait for the [`System.Threading.Task`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx) to complete (or timeout) before returning to the client.

```
public class ApiController
{
    private readonly Software _software;
    private readonly BlockingCollection<WorkItem> _workQueue;

    public ApiController(Software software, BlockingCollection<WorkItem> workQueue)
    {
        _software = software;
        _workQueue = workQueue;
    }

    // Async action method optional
    public async Task<SoftwareOutput> ExecuteAsync(SoftwareInput input)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<SoftwareOutput>();
        var workItem = new WorkItem(input, tcs);

        _workQueue.Add(workItem);
        _software.ForceIdleEvent();

        using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)))
        {
            cts.Token.Register(() => tcs.TrySetCanceled());
            return await tcs.Task;
        }
    }
}

public class AddIn
{
    private readonly Software _software;
    private readonly BlockingCollection<WorkItem> _workQueue;

    public AddIn(Software software, BlockingCollection<WorkItem> workQueue)
    {
        _software = software;
        _workQueue = workQueue;

        _software.Idle += OnSoftwareIdle;
    }

    private void OnSoftwareIdle(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WorkItem workItem;
        while (_workQueue.TryTake(out workItem))
        {
            var softwareOutput = _software.DoSoftwareWork(workItem.Input);
            workItem.TaskCompletionSource.TrySetResult(softwareOutput);
        }
    }
}

public class WorkItem
{
    public WorkItem(SoftwareInput input, TaskCompletionSource<SoftwareOutput> tcs)
    {
        Input = input;
        TaskCompletionSource = tcs;
    }

    public SoftwareInput Input { get; }
    public TaskCompletionSource<SoftwareOutput> TaskCompletionSource { get; }
}
```

This does feel awfully hacky using the idle event like this to ensure work is executed on the correct thread. A better solution would be to marshal work directly if possible. I can't really comment without knowing more about the particular software.

> the .NET API for this software only allows accessing data from specific threads created by the API itself. Usually this is an instance of a custom Command class which is triggered by a user requesting to run the command.

Are these run on a UI thread? Check to see if [`SynchronizationContext.Current`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.current(v=vs.110).aspx) is not null inside the `Command` classes. If so, then it may be as simple as exposing the same context to the web API controller and marshalling the work with `context.Post()`.